# Difference between LanguageResource and Resources

Tags: c#, .net, resources, resx

What is the difference between LanguageResource and Resources?
i.e

```
string hello = LanguageResource.Language.wordHello
```

and

```
string hello = Resources.Language.wordHello
```

One thing I did notice, sadly in a bad way is that Resources seems to only work locally? The ones I call with Resources return the error

> The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context

On a live webpage while locally they work great

Meanwhile LanguageResource works both locally and live

But what is really the difference between these? And is there a way for me to make Resources work live rather than having to change all the Resources to LanguageResource?

Comment: Both appear to be custom classes developed in your company or provided by framework or project you are using. Error most likely indicates that in some files using declaration at the top of the file is not included for the namespace where Resources class is declared in.